# sqlite3_prepare_v2 failure: near "SELECT": syntax error

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables called "decks" and "notes"

I tried to SELECT table like this:

```
SELECT id,
       title,COUNT(SELECT lastStatus FROM notes WHERE deckId=id and lastStatus='good') AS goodNotes 
FROM decks
```

but I got this error:

> sqlite3_prepare_v2 failure: near "SELECT": syntax error

Comment: which database are you using,please avoid add different database together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `MySQL`, you can use below sql:

```
SELECT d.id,d.title,COUNT(n.lastStatus) AS goodNotes 
   FROM decks d 
   join notes n ON n.deckId=d.id and n.lastStatus='good'
   GROUP BY d.id,t.title
```